# Hello How to set something in java inside the new response

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I could not figure out how to set inside the new response. Or is there any other way to do it?

My Request:

```
public class SthRequest extends BaseRequest {
  private String dataToSth;
}
```

My Response:

```
public class SthResponse extends BaseResponse {
  private String sthData;
}
```

My logic code

```
@Component
public class SthQueryCommand implements BaseCommand<SthRequest, SthResponse> {
  @Override
  public SthResponse perform(SthRequest req) {
    String out = "";
    for (String mask : req.getDataToMask().split("\\s+")) {
      String startChar = mask.substring(0, 1);
      String endChar = mask.substring(mask.length() - 1, mask.length());
      out += startChar + "***" + endChar;
    }
    out.trim();

    return new MaskingResponse(perform(req).setSthData(out));
  }
}
```

İs there any way to do it?

Comment: Note that `out.trim()` does nothing, effectively. It should be `out = out.trim()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything that you need.
So you can do so:

```
SthResponse sthResponse  = new SthResponse();
sthResponse.setSthData(out);
return sthResponse;
```